# Change the DIV's color based on child class/content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make the `<span>`'s background color of person 1 to be in a different color than person 2.

I tried this method and it didn't work:

```js
$('span.Message').each(function() {

  if ($(this).find('span.person1').length > 0) {
    $("span.person1").parent().css("background", "yellow");
  } else {
    $("span.person1").parent().css("background", "red");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Message">
    <img alt="" src="images/person1.png">
    <span class="person1">Person 1 Name</span>: Hi, how are you?
</span>

<span class="Message">
    <img alt="" src="images/person2.png">
    <span class="person2">Person 2 Name</span>: Good, how are you?
</span>
```

Comment: do you have to do this via jQuery? Is there a reason you can't just have some css on class `.person2` to have a `background: red;` ?

Comment: Why not use plain CSS for this? `.person1{...} and .person2{...}`

Comment: @j08691 Because looking at the attempt in jQuery, the OP wishes to change the background color of `span.Message` depending on whether it contains `.person1` or `.person2`.

Comment: @j08691 because it's a div inside a div, so if I change the background color, it would change only around the text and not the whole message bubble.

Comment: A "a div inside a div"? Looks more like a span in a span.

Comment: @ChristopherMesser because it's a div inside a div, so if I change the background color, it would change only around the text and not the whole message bubble.

Comment: @j08691 ok whatever the case is, I meant that they are two elements ...

Comment: So what are you trying to do, change the background of .person1 and .person2, or change the background of their parent span? The first sentence in your question says "I want to make the <span>'s background color of person 1 to be in a different color than person 2." but your code sort of contradicts that.

Comment: @j08691 Yeah I think my questions isn't great enough. I want to change the span.Message of the parent of span.person1 to be let's say red, and span.person2 in yellow. The guys gave me great solutions but it's not working because it's an ongoing chat conversation.

Answer (score 1):

You should `$(this)` inside of the your `if() { } else { }` instead of `span.person1`, otherwise you're always selecting the same element, regardless of its contents.

You can simply set `$(this).css()` inside of the your `each()` function, and use a ternary operator to choose the colour, depending upon the length of the `find()` function as follows:

```js
$('span.Message').each(function() {
  var bg = ($(this).find('span.person1').length) ? 'yellow' : 'red';
  $(this).css('background', bg);
});
```

```css
span.Message {
display: block;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="Message">
  <img alt="" src="images/person1.png">
  <span class="person1">Person 1 Name</span>: Hi, how are you?
</span>

<span class="Message">
  <img alt="" src="images/person2.png">
  <span class="person2">Person 2 Name</span>: Good, how are you?
</span>
```

Comment: one thing I forgot to mention, that this is an on going chat between two people, and the script you wrote runs only once when the page loads, so it doesn't change colors after it updates.

Comment: @MustafaZubaidi That's a separate question that wasn't included in your OP, hence this does answer the question you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
$('span.Message').each(function() {
     if($(this).find('span.person1').length > 0){
        $(this).closest('.Message').css("background", "yellow");
     }
   else{
       $(this).closest('.Message').css("background", "red");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Message">
<img alt="" src="images/person1.png">
<span class="person1">Person 1 Name</span>: Hi, how are you?
</span>

<span class="Message">
<img alt="" src="images/person2.png">
<span class="person2">Person 2 Name</span>: Good, how are you?
</span>
```

Comment: one thing I forgot to mention, that this is an on going chat between two people, and the script you wrote runs only once when the page loads, so it doesn't change colors after it updates.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function rowColor() at the instance when an event is fired at the time when a new message thread is generated

```
 function rowColor(){$('.Message').each(function(i,v) {   if(i%2 == 0)
 {$(this).addClass("Person1");}
 else
 {$(this).addClass("Person2");}});}
```

Put the below definitions in your stylesheet

```
.Person1{background-color:#e6f6f7}.Person2{background-color:#a0d8de}
```

Comment: this snippet should work fine for n iterations of class Message. I hope it helps

Comment: one thing I forgot to mention, that this is an on going chat between two people, and the script you wrote runs only once when the page loads, so it doesn't change colors after it updates.